# Returning min, max and the nearest multiple value of a number

Tags: c#

I need a function that will return the following values and conditions:

Higher, Lower or Equal to Min/Max Range

> If the inputted value is higher or equal to max, returns max
>   If the inputted value is lower or equal to min, returns min

Within Min/Max Range

> If the inputted value is within the range, returns the nearest multiple of a certain number (e.g. predefined resolution like 0.010)

---

```
public double MinMaxRange(double value)
{
    if (value >= max)
    { return max; }
    else if (value <= min)
    { return min; }
    /* I am not quite sure if it can return the
       nearest multiple value of a certain number
       including the smaller decimal numbers like
       0.0000005 */
    else
    {
        double multiple = 0.010;
        double rem = value % multiple;
        double result = value - rem;
        if (rem > (multiple / 2))
            result += multiple;
    }
}
```

Comment: This place isn't for solving your own homework. Show us some code examples of what youv'e already tried to do.

Comment: stack overflow won't allow me to upload images but I have my draft, i just can't upload it

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You can add code to your question and use the code formatter in the editor {}. No need for an image.

Comment: Thank you, Yooz! I will update my question in a jiffy

Comment: public double MinMaxRange(double value) 
{
if (value>= max) 
{ 
return max;
} 
else if (value<=min)
{ 
return min;
} 
//I am not quite sure if it can return the nearest multiple value of a certain number including the smaller decimal numbers like 0.0000005//
else 
{
decimal multiple = 0.010
decimal rem = value % multiple;
decimal result = value - rem;
if (rem > (multiple / 2))
    result += multiple;
}

Comment: @newbie_coder - You can edit your question. That's 100% better than adding code in comments.

Comment: @are you working with `decimal` or `double`? You should pick one. What values are you trying to represent? Money, length, weight, etc?

Comment: thank you, enigmativity for editing it using the formatter, iam currently using my phone                      i'll stick with double

Comment: i'm trying to represent voltage levels including its resolution (thats for the multiple part)

Comment: I think the code looks reasonable. You got specs, you got code.. What is the actual problem?

Comment: This is a perfect scenario to try writing some unit tests. It's a little bit of extra learning, but please trust me when I tell you that it will pay off 1000 times over. Either before or after writing your function you can write simple automated tests that show what result you expect for a given set of inputs. The world would be a better place if more emphasis was placed on unit testing when teaching developers.

Comment: I believe the only thing missing here is `return result;` in the `else` block.

Comment: is there any other way to shorten the code? make it more compact

Comment: i perform unit testing on my code and there were 6 notable errors found.. did I miss some conditions? or do I need to add another block of code?

Comment: I tested the following inputs for Min, Max, Res and Values a.) 0, -6, 0.001, -5.999 b.) 0, -26, 0.01, -26.01 c.) 0, -26, 0.01, 25 d.) 0, -6, 0.001, 0.001 e.) 0, -6, 0.001, -4.0001

Comment: it should return values -5.999, -26, 0, 0, -4 respectively but instead it returns -6, 0, -26, -6, -6